# How to exclude a child in children selector using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a parent element div `#mmm-a` set to `visibility`, `hidden` by previous `on click` function and I'm using the following code to make it reappear on a page (on click):

```js
jQuery("#mmm-a").css("visibility", "visible").fadeTo(300, 1);
```

This works fine, but when I trying to exclude a child `#mmm-b` from its parent div `#mmm-a` it didn't work, I'm tried this (and variations):

```js
jQuery("#mmm-a").not("#mmm-b").css("visibility", "visible").fadeTo(300, 1);
```

What is wrong with my code? How do I make the whole div visible again, but keep one element inside it hidden?

Comment: How one element can has two id?

Comment: why would you assume that? @Mohammad

Comment: Because `jQuery("#mmm-a").not("#mmm-b")` mean select `#mmm-a` that han not id `mmm-b`

Comment: Ok, parent div has an ID, child div has an ID. How to make it work? @Mohammad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jQuery("#mmm-a")` selects only the single element with the ID "mmm-a". The `.not("#mmm-b")` wouldn't exclude anything from that selection -- it's still a single-element list.    (The only way that would work is if the same element had both IDs: then the `.not()` would exclude it, winding up with a zero-element selection -- but this is impossible because one element can't have two IDs.)

A multi-element selection excluding a single child would look more like `$('#mmm-a').find(':not(#mmm-b)')` or `$('#mmm-a :not(#mmm-b)')` -- these would return a list of all child elements of mmm-a which are not mmm-b.

But that won't help you here either, because, you're using `fadeTo` which animates element's *opacity*, not its visibility.  Opacity always affects child elements: a zero-opacity element will always have all of its contents at zero opacity, it's not possible to exclude a child from that.

Unlike opacity, child elements *can* be excluded from `visibility` rules:

```css
#a {visibility:hidden}
#b {visibility:visible}
```

```html
<div id="a"> hidden parent
  <div id="b">visible child</div>
</div>
```

...but `visibility` can't be animated (there's no partial state between "visible" and "hidden".)

If you need the parent's opacity to animate but the child's to stay visible, the only way is to restructure your HTML such that the element to stay visible isn't a child element of the one to be hidden.

EDIT: per comments below, though, you want to do this the other way around:

> I want to child element to stay hidden while rest of a div fade to visible again, to manipulate child visibility later

...which is much easier!

```js
$('#go').on("click", function() {
  $('#b').css("visibility","hidden"); // hide child element
  $('#a')
    .css("opacity","0") // set opacity to 0 first, so the animation will work later
    .css("visibility","visible") // set visiblity to visible
    .fadeTo(300, 1) // animate opacity from 0 to 1
});
```

```css
#a, #v {visibility: hidden}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a"> parent made visible
  <div id="b">child stays hidden</div>
</div>
<button id="go">Click me</button>
```

Comment: I want to child element to stay hidden while rest of a div fade to visible again, to manipulate child visibility later @Daniel Beck

Comment: I didn't mentioned it earlier but I can't use .hide() or other equivalent of `display none`, only `visibility`, thats why I posted a question since I didn't find a way to it to work on my own @Daniel Beck

Comment: Changed the second code sample to set visibility instead of using 'hide()`, same thing.

Comment: Ok, as I wrote in my question the `mmm-a` div is **already** hidden including all its child (and it must stay that way), by animation I want to make this whole div visible again **but not** one of its child `mmm-b` @Daniel Beck

Comment: That's exactly what I showed in my second example. A is hidden. A contains B. The click handler keeps B hidden and fades A in.

Comment: What you are suggesting its not working in my case since visibility hidden applied to whole div by previous on click function (this is must stay as it is), I get it but it didn't work as in your example @Daniel Beck

Comment: I made one last edit, then, to set the visibility as well as the opacity on the parent.

Comment: Now, it is obvious, it didn’t work from the begging since it’s not just visibility hidden which is applied to the whole div, it’s also **previous** animation set its opacity to “0” (on entire div), that’s why it’s still a problem

Comment: Yep -- opacity and visibility are separate properties; if you use `fadeTo()` you're animating the opacity; that won't affect its `visibility` property (or vice-versa).

Comment: Ok, thank you anyway! I will be thinking of how to solve this without changing previous “steps”

Answer (score 0):

The `jQuery("#mmm-a").not("#mmm-b")`
meaning select `#mmm-a` that han not id `mmm-b` whereas you need to exclude special child from list of childrens.

Use this instead

```js
$("#mmm-a :not(#mmm-b)").css("visibility", "visible");
```

```css
#mmm-a {visibility: hidden}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mmm-a">
  <div>1</div>
  <div id="mmm-b">#mmm-b</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not `or` but an exact second example. As the first one changes css for each nested element, not children.